Add line to toc from external pdf and hyperlink it
I have some parts of the document that I want to import to LaTeX but its bookmark does not come along, I'm fine with that and can manually create a new one using addtotoc inside \includepdf. The problem is the chapter created by addtotoc is the numbering one, how can I make the unnumbered chapter that refers to the page from an external pdf while toc can hyperlink to that page and also has a bookmark appear on the pdf viewer.
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\addtotocunnumbered}[3]{% First is level name,2 title,3 page number
    \bookmark[page=#3,level=0]{#2}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{#2}{#3}{}}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    
    \includepdf[pages=-, offset=1in -1in, addtotoc={
        1,chapter,0,Chapter 1,c1
    }]{example-image.pdf}
    
    \addtotocunnumbered{chapter}{Chapter 2}{2}
    \addtotocunnumbered{chapter}{Chapter 3}{5}
    
\end{document}

And this is what I got,

unfortunately, chapters 2 and 3 do not appear when I compile this example, I want chapters 2 and 3 to appear the same as Chapter 1 both in the bookmark and toc except not have a number before its title e.g. just "Chapter 1" not "1 Chapter 1".

Show a small but complete example that demonstrates what you get now and describe what you want to get instead. (You can use example-image.pdf as pdf)

@UlrikeFischer I have added the example now.

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}  %chapters should be unnumbered  
    \includepdf[pages=1-5,
     addtotoc={
        1,chapter,0,Chapter 1,c1,
        2,chapter,0,Chapter 2,c2,
        5,chapter,0,Chapter 5,c3}
     ]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}
    
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2} %or whatever    
    
\end{document}



Thank you, I've been struggling with this problem for days.

If this answers your question you should accept it.
